# Why do I always get undefined variable error even though I'm passing the variable correctly to the view?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

Why do I always get `Undefined variable $var` error?  I'm trying to work with one view only (`my_view.blade.php`) but for some reason, when I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I get the aforementioned error.

My intention's to make the `$var` variable available in the view so I can use it in the blade file. This variable gets populated only when the user enters text and submits but for some reason, I can't even get to part where I can see the text input field because this file gets thrown upon loading the view.  If I get rid `{{ $var }}`, everything works as intended.

I thought this whole time I'm doing it correctly in terms of passing a variable to the view.  What am I doing wrong?

controller:

```
public function addVar(Request $request) {
    $var = $request->get('var');

    Url::create([
        'var' => $var
    ]);
    
    view('my_view', compact('var'));

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('my_view');
});

Route::post('/add-var', [MyController::class, 'addVar'])->name('add-var');
```

my_view.blade.php:

```
{{ $var }}

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('add-var') }}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="var" placeholder="Enter text"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: try this: `return Redirect::back()->with('var', $var)`

Comment: `return view('my_view');` causes an issue cause you need to pass `var` to it.

Comment: @Faesal Yeah `var`'s being passed inside `compact()`.

Comment: no you do that in `addVar` method that is called when you call `/add-var` route but when you call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` you just call this method `return view('my_view');` without sending your `$var`

Comment: @Faesal oh I see what you mean.  Is there anyway I can do that in the web.php file?  Like a dynamic placeholder for the 2nd param in `view()` inside `web.php`

Comment: `return view('my_view', ['var' => 'value']);` or you can add `compact` instead of the array

Comment: you wanna the two routes make the same thing and return the same view ?

Comment: @Faesal yeah exactly, that's what I want to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240059/discussion-between-faesal-and-sp92).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna the two routes do the same thing

In `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', [MyController::class, 'addVar']);

Route::post('/add-var', [MyController::class, 'addVar'])->name('add-var');
```

In `my_view.blade.php`:

```
{{ $var ?? '' }}

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('add-var') }}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="var" placeholder="Enter text"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  It just makes a `GET` request about 12 times according to the network tab with a `302` error.